# How to reassign -- and --- in unicode fonts?

Tags: fonts, xetex, punctuation

In XeTeX, after loading the font `lmroman10-regular.otf`, -- and --- are not matched to en- and em-dashes.

```
Here-have--some---text.

\font\rm="[lmroman10-regular.otf]"
\rm
Here-have--some---text.
\bye
```

[image]

How can I remap them?

Comment: Look for `mapping=tex-text` in the small XeTeX manual

Comment: Are you using XeTeX or XeLaTeX? If the latter, you could use the option `Ligatures=TeX` of the `fontspec` package, as in `\usepackage{fontspec}` and `\fontspec[Ligatures=TeX]{lmroman10-regular.otf}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Plain XeTeX you have to add the `mapping` feature:

```
\font\rm="[lmroman10-regular.otf]:mapping=tex-text"
\rm
Here-have--some---text.
\bye
```

[image]

This also enables `` ?` `` for ¿, `` !` `` for ¡, ``` `` ``` for “, `''` for ”, `<<` for « and `>>` for » and `,,` for the German low quotes.